# Do I need to winterize 40' underground hose?

Tags: water, winterizing, hose

I want to bury a 40 foot garden hose from my outdoor tap to a hose reel.

The tap itself will be winterized. And the hose reel will be stored in-house for the winter.

But do I need to winterize that 40 foot piece of hose that's gonna stay underground? Both ends of it would be open. Wouldn't the expanding water just come out the end?

If not, how should I do it?

Winter in Canada

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Blow it out with air.

Over simplified example: the ends may freeze first, then when more freezes in the middle it has nowhere to go.

There is a [gadget](http://a.co/8U3SRWf) for this if you want to use a compressor.   Essentially an adapter "air compressor male to hose fitting".

These adapters are available in several configurations notabley male and female hose bib such as: 
[image]

[image]

Or, if unavailable, make one with 2 or 3 parts from the big box store.

Comment: You could also suck it out with a shop vac.

Comment: What kind of pressure do I need from an air compressor? Would [something like this](https://www.shopatshowcasecanada.com/products/air-dragon?utm_medium=cpc&utm_source=googlepla&variant=35315504518&gclid=Cj0KEQjwo-XIBRCOycL7hsuI_NoBEiQAuS6HtMhXpeqoExtcji_3Rb3Ti_BKQJ5BN5c9M3Y3HsOrjb8aAqKD8P8HAQ) work, or is that too small?

Comment: It isn't so much about pressure as flow volume. I wouldn't expect that tool to do well. Flip a vacuum around and blow it out with that.

Comment: You could of course blow with a shop vac, and if you do, you will eliminate getting any water in your vac. I personally wouldn't want to blow with the shop vac because of all the nasty stuff in there which would then go into the bird watering stations. If you have a leaf blower, that takes in cleaner outdoor air.

Comment: There is a [gadget](http://a.co/8U3SRWf) for this if you want to use a compressor.   The problem you will have using a shop vac is sealing the end of the vac hose to the buried hose. a shop vac should have enough air push tho.

Comment: @Slav the device u linked might be fine, you still have e to figure the connection out however.  Here is a [far less expensive portable](https://www.amazon.com/dp/B000SL4AA2/ref=cm_sw_r_cp_api_diDgzbRGG7ZYS) tho that I'm certain could do the job.  As an added bonus the included blue adapter may just fit the interior diameter of your hose.

Comment: Blowing out the water with air is standard practice around here (New England) for winterizing buried lawn sprinkler/irrigation systems.